# Give user total control to all subsites

Tags: wss-3.0, custom-masterpage, content-editor-web-part, sub-site

I am in a sharepoint application that was already built using MOSS 2007.

At this application my user has total control on the admnistration and is a administrator on the root website `http://rootwebsite`, but not on the subsites.

I used the `Check Effective Permissions` from the `Sharepoint Administrations Toolkit` and is showing that my user has:

```
Total Control, Limited Access | Given Directly 
Collaboration, Limited Access | Subsite 2
Collaboration, Limited Access | Subsite 3
Collaboration, Limited Access | Subsite 4
.
.
```

And in `Site Collection Administrator` I am one of the administrators.
Now I am trying to edit the page where the search goes.

```
http://www.servername.com/_layouts/searchresults.aspx
```

and there isnt the `edit` option on `action` button.
How can I make this user to have a total control of all subsites ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The searchresults.aspx page is used farm-wide, not for a specific site or site collection. This page is essentially an application page, which is why you can't edit it. If you need a custom search page, you'll need to build a page, add the applicable web parts, then tell your site to use that custom page instead of the default farm-wide one.

Comment: Sorry to make 2 questions in one, I am new in sharepoint.

Comment: No worries... you've got to start somewhere...

Comment: Do you know how to redirect this page to a one where I can customize it ? I can't find this information anywhere.